# Python add ', ' to string and return:

Tags: python-3.x

```
fd = open(nom_fichier, 'r')
    liste_chaine = fd.readlines() 
    liste_chaine2 = []

    for item in liste_chaine:
        if item not in "'noir\n','blanc\n','Humain\n', 'Ordinateur\n', 'False\n', 'True\n":
            liste_chaine2.append(item)



    liste_chaine2 = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in liste_chaine2]

    return liste_chaine2
```

['3,3,blanc', '3,4,noir', '4,3,noir', '4,4,blanc']

i am reading a file and trying to return a string output exactly like :

```
3,3,blanc
4,3,noir
3,4,white
```

i cleaned the file with the code above but  need to clean up this list to the required output

Comment: sorry its returning

Comment: you probably used `"".join` instead of `",".join`. Show your code

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: I have modified and added much more info as requested, if you need more let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string and put it together again to meet your requirements:

```
string = '33blanc 34noir 43noir 44blanche'
result = '\n'.join(['{},{},{}'.format(v[0], v[1], v[2:]) for v in string.split()])
print(result)
```

> 3,3,blanc
>
> 3,4,noir
>
> 4,3,noir
>
> 4,4,blanche

Comment: you should not answer unclear questions like that. It's just like guessing

Comment: Actually my return is a sting on every line  so that doesnt work. my bad i didnt explain correctly. The striing is 33blanc, then a new line...

Comment: Thanks Aurora your code really helped me finish my method.